# How to call method by string?

Tags: python

Can I call a method to process data by combining strings?

For example, it is OK to type `data.image.truecolor()` in code?

```
data.image.truecolor() # This line is successful to call method
```

My problem is: if I have a data object named data (not a string), how to combine `".image.truecolor"` sting to call method to process the data?

It is like:

```
result=getattr(data,".image.truecolor")
result() # which is equivalent to the code above
```

Of course, it is failed. I got a `AttributeError`.

Because there are many methods to process data, for example:

```
data.image.fog()
data.image.ir108()
data.image.dnb()
data.image.overview()
# .... and other many methods
```

It is stupid and ugly to type the code by hand, isn't it?

By this reason, I hope I can use this code:

```
methods=["fog","ir108","dnb","overview"]
for method in methods:
    method=".image"+method
    result=getattr(data,method) # to call method to process the data
    result()  # to get the data processed
```

Is it possible to do by this way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
methods=["fog","ir108","dnb","overview"]
dataImage = data.image
for method in methods:
    result = getattr(dataImage ,method) # to call method to process the data
    result()  # to get the data processed
```

Why not like this when you know you will be invoking methods of `data.image`? Otherwise, if you didn't know the second property, `image`, you'd have had to use two levels of `getattr` as suggested in the other answers.

Comment: Thank you, but this way is not successful.Because the final data is processed by many different class(include different modules), I still get a AttributeError by dataImage=data.image. However, I know how to do it by your help. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry....... Now it is successful! because I use "data=data.image", to save memory space by Python's gabarge collection(I have 16GB im my computer, it is still not enough), it is falied, so I guess it it also failed to assign to different variable. However, I try dataImage=data.image, it is successful! Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You need a two level `getattr`:

```
im = getattr(data, 'image')
result=getattr(im, method)
result()
```

Comment: What's the point of the first `getattr` if its second argument is constant? `meth = getattr(data.image, method)` would be more readable.

Comment: It was not clear (at least to me) from the OP question if the 'image' part was always constant.

Comment: Their code sample made it appear quite constant, it's just that the OP expected something like `getattr(data, "image.%s" % method)` to work (omitting the `.` to boot).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `getattr` for getting class instance methods by name, here's an example:

```
class A():
    def print_test(self):
        print "test"

a = A()
getattr(a, 'print_test')()  # prints 'test'
```

And, in your case, there will be two `getattr`s, one for image and one for the image method:

```
methods=["fog","ir108","dnb","overview"]
image = getattr(data, 'image')
for method in methods:
    result = getattr(image, method)
    result()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `eval("data.image.fog()")`as well, to call/evaluate a expression in a string.